# Passing one or more array as parameters into method in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to create a method that takes in one or more parameters but when I try the following code I get the following error message.

```
struct SomeStruct {
    static func method(arrays: AnyObject[]...) -> AnyObject[] {
        return []
    }
}
SomeStruct.method([1], [2])


Cannot convert the expression's type 'AnyObject[]' to type 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'
```

If I run the following code

```
SomeStruct.method(["1"], ["2"])
```

I get the following error

```
Cannot convert the expression's type 'AnyObject[]' to type 'ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralConvertible'
```

I want to allow 0 or more array of items to be passed into this method of any element type including numbers. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: This code compiles and runs fine for me...If you're in the playground, try relaunching it. I've hit some bugs that left it wacky.

Comment: Works fine in the Playground

Comment: Attaching screenshot of the error I get in Playground. I am running Mac OS X Yosemite. Not sure if this is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by using a generic instead of AnyObject.

```
struct SomeStruct {
    static func method<T>(arrays: T[]...) -> T[] {
        return []
    }
}
SomeStruct.method([1], [2])
```